# Adding real zeros to a dataset vs. presence-only modeling?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, dataset, model

I have a fisheries dataset for which I have calculated the number of fishing sets in each grid cell (100 km x 100 km) for each month of every year. Fishermen in this fishery are legally required to report their effort. There are many cells that had no fishing effort in them in a specific month/year; because of the requirement, I know that these are real zeros. I currently am using the fishing effort data for models. I am running models with only the fishing data (e.g., not any of the zeros).

It has been recommended that I run either a GLMM with a zero-truncated Poisson and total effort for each month/year as a random variable. Count of sets in each cell is the response variable.

I have also tried beta regression with the proportion of total sets of each month/year for each cell as the response variable.

My question is: do I need to create a matrix that has every zero for cells that didn't have fishing effort in a particular month/year? There are over 1600 cells.

I do not think I need to add these zeros in, because they are uninformative, but I wanted to make sure I'm thinking about this correctly.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't get it: if your models use only the data where there was nonzero effort, then what would be the reason to create such a superfluous matrix? What role does it play in the modeling?

Comment: That's what I'm asking - is there a need to add those real zeros in or am I okay just looking at then nonzero effort? Maybe I'm doing the right thing...

Comment: How can we tell? You haven't provided any information at all about your models.

Comment: Thanks, @whuber. I am still trying to figure out which models to use, but I have added information to my original post to clarify. Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Comment: I dont beleive the zeros are uninformative, they tell us the fishermen dont beleive there to be much fish there, and certainly have their reasons for that ...

Comment: To expand a bit on whuber's question: what research question are you trying to answer with your models?

Comment: I am trying to determine whether fishing effort (over time) has moved closer to a location (over space). The effort varies by month and year based on environmental and economic factors. I was thinking that I'd either a) sum the sets in each 100 km x 100 km cell for every month/year and model that with the total number of sets in that month/year as a variable (or offset) or b) have the response variable be the proportion of total sets in that month/year. I want to know whether there are more sets close to this location over time (accounting for annual and monthly changes in fishing effort).